# Stackoverflow editor url replacement in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to simulate something similar to stackoverflow editor behavior for replacing text and url in php. I am having troubles finding the right regex or the right way to simulate this.

> sample text

```
We have [@url|first url|1] and 
the [@url|the second url|2] and then [@url|the third url|3]

[1]: https://www.google.com
[2]: www.facebook.com 
[3]: http://www.amazon.com
```

> expected result

We have [first url](https://www.google.com) and [the second url](http://www.facebook.com) and then [the third url](http://www.amazon.com).

Comment: Please take a look here https://regex101.com/r/GBR1AX/1

Comment: @revo nice... you really should write that up as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex captures required parts like the text and URL:

```
\[@url\|([^|]+)\|(\d+)\](?=(?>.*\R+)+^\[\2]:\s+(\S+))
```

Regex [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/GBR1AX/2/)

Breakdown:

- `\[@url\|([^|]+)\|(\d+)\]` Match a @url block and capture both text and index
- `(?=` Start of positive lookahead

  - `(?>` Start of atomic (non-capturing) group

    - `.*\R+` Match a line and its following linebreaks
  - `)+` End of group, repeat at least once
  - `^\[\2]:\s+(\S+)` Match an index according to our captured index number above and capture the URL
- `)` End of positive lookahead

and the following matches indices at the end:

```
^\[\d+]:\h+\S+
```

So here we will use `preg_replace_callback` to replace those blocks with their corresponding anchor tag and remove the indices:

```
$re = '/\[@url\|([^|]+)\|(\d+)\](?=(?>.*\R+)+^\[\2]:\s+(\S+))|^\[\d+]:\h+\S+/m';
echo preg_replace_callback($re, function($match) {
    if (isset($match[1])) {
        return "<a href=\"{$match[3]}\">{$match[1]}</a>";
    }
}, $str);
```

PHP [live demo here](https://3v4l.org/B4ptj)